# Get value of input element in event listener with d3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, input, dom-events

I have two html elements:

```
<input id="searchInput">
<div id="searchText"></div>
```

I'm using d3 to add a listener in a script.

```
d3.select("#searchInput").on("keyup",getSearchText);
```

I need a function that prints a value of input to a div

```
function getSearchText(value) {
d3.select("#searchResults").html(value.toString());
}
```

But I don't know how to pass input value parameter to a listener function.

Comment: Not too familiar with `d3`, but shouldn't `this.value` give you the value?

Comment: Tried that. d3.select("#searchInput").value returns undefined.

Comment: No no, try using `d3.select("#searchResults").html(this.value);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using an instance of `this` to get the value:

```
d3.select("#searchResults").html(this.value);
```

Comment: In `ES6`, if your handler is an _arrow function_, how would you write this?

Answer (score 4):

I've found solution:

```
d3.select("#id").node().value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the third argument:

```
function getSearchText(d, i, o) {
  const myValue = o[0].value;
}
```