# How to get a value of select with d3?

Tags: javascript, html, select, d3.js

I need a d3 code that does this:
`document.getElementById("paramSelector").value`

I've tried this:
`d3.select("#paramSelector").attr("value")`
and it returns null

Comment: You will need to call `.value` on the element anyway, so I don't see a reason to use D3 here.

Comment: Oh… actually you already asked the same question O_o http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527872/get-value-of-input-element-in-event-listener-with-d3

Answer (score 0):

change your call to

```
d3.select("#paramSelector").html(this.value);
```

take care changing your `.attr` to `.html`