# How to get value from the element using selection in d3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm using D3 with SVG and having one question regarding selections.

I have an element in th DOM like the following:

```
<g class="tooltip">
    // some other code
    <text class="name">Testing D3</text>
</g>
```

Now I want to get the text **"Testing D3"** using selections. How can I do it?

I've tried the following:

```
d3.select(".tooltip .name").text
d3.select(".tooltip .name").value
d3.select(".tooltip .name").textContent
d3.select(".tooltip .name").html
```

But none of them is working.

I've also tried using

```
d3.select(".tooltip .name").html(this.value);
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527872/get-value-of-input-element-in-event-listener-with-d3) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964503/how-to-get-a-value-of-select-with-d3), but that's giving me an `SVGTextElement` & not the actual value.

Also I cannot use `document.getElementById("name");`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883675/d3-js-get-value-of-selected-option), because I have to achieve this functionality through d3 only.

Please note that **name** is a single element.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a child selector here (and call the `.text()` function):

```
d3.select("g.tooltip > text.name").text();
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but can you please tell me what is child selector? And what does this syntax (code inside select) mean? Can you please explain it?

Comment: The `>` is the child selector. It selects a `text` element of class `name` that is a child of a `g` element of class `tooltip`.

Comment: But it's giving me null.

Comment: Yes it was my mistake. Thanks. But I would also like to point that, if I select the element I've shown in question, I don't need to use the child selector. The problem was with `text()` method.